# Open Mvim with a vertical split on start

Tags: vim

I am always using mvim with a vertical split so everytime I open it i have to manually type in `:vsp` to create one.

Is there a way to have mvim directly splitted on start up?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need two empty vertical windows at startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.vimrc` in you home dirctory, then put `vsp` in it.

```
# run this in you terminal
echo vsp >> ~/.vimrc
```